# Text not vertically aligned within tabular with nested tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, nesting

I am trying to vertically align a row heading with a table inside the row. But no matter what I do, the heading remains in the center. I tried using `p{'width'}`, but that had no change.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}l l}
        \Large{Row Heading 1} & Some text that can span the entire page. \vspace{6pt} \\
        \Large{Row Heading 2} & \begin{tabular}{@{}l l}
        {Column heading 1} & \hspace{1in} {Column Heading 2} \\
        \small{Column data} & \hspace{1in} \small{Column data} \\
        \small{Column data} & \hspace{1in} \small{Column data} \\
        \\
        {Column heading 3} & \hspace{1in} {Column heading 4} \\
        \small{Column data} & \hspace{1in} \small{Column data} \\
        \small{Column data} & \hspace{1in} \small{Column data} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. On this site, questions should include a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @SandyG I edited my question so the code was a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to align "Row Heading 2" with the top row of the "inner" `tabular` environment, you should change the setup of the inner `tabular` from

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l l}  % [t] for "top alignment".
```

Here's a cleaned-up version of your example code. Note that `\Large` and `\small` are switches, i.e., they don't take arguments. I've also replaced `\vspace{6pt} \\` with the more idiomatic expression `\\[6pt]`, and I've gotten rid of the six `\hspace{1in}` directives by making the inter-column spacing a part of the definition of the inner `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l X@{}}
\Large Row Heading 1 & Some text that can span the entire page. \\[6pt]
\Large Row Heading 2  & 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{\hspace{1in}} l @{}}
   Column heading 1    & Column heading 2\\
   \small Column data  & Column data     \\
   \small Column data  & Column data     \\
   \\ % empty row
   Column heading 3   & Column heading 4   \\
   \small Column data & \small Column data \\
   \small Column data & \small Column data \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```